# Non-linear curve fitting with multiple parameters and conditional expression

Tags: fitting

[image: Bloch-Gruneissen formula]

The above integral(Bloch Gruneissen formula) is what i like to fit with my experimental data.I am new to Mathematica. To cross-check the fit results obtained in other software, I try to fit with my experimental data(Resistivity Vs Temperature) using this software. I make the integral analytical and then i get a conditional expression at the end..Following the steps as

1. mydata = ReadList["Sheet1.dat", Number,   RecordLists -> True];

   ```
   mydata={{50.3838, 0.241641}, {50.886, 0.242787}, {51.3245, 
   0.243584}, {51.8868, 0.244274}, {52.2609, 0.244107}, {52.6343, 
   0.245124}, {53.0692, 0.246065}, {53.5032, 0.246445}, {53.9364, 
   0.247621}, {54.3688, 0.248046}, {54.8004, 0.248783}, {55.2927, 
   0.250672}, {55.7226, 0.250763}, {56.2743, 0.252342}, {56.6414, 
   0.25238}, {57.069, 0.253314}, {57.5569, 0.25537}, {57.9831, 
   0.255082}, {58.4087, 0.256258}, {58.8943, 0.2577}, {59.3185, 
   0.25852}, {59.8026, 0.259537}, {60.2859, 0.26019}, {60.6479, 
   0.26129}, {61.0698, 0.261632}, {61.5512, 0.263006}, {61.972, 
   0.263711}, {62.5122, 0.264979}, {62.9319, 0.266193}, {63.411, 
   0.266641}, {63.8895, 0.267749}, {64.3675, 0.269039}, {64.8449, 
   0.269191}, {65.2623, 0.270026}, {65.7389, 0.271741}, {66.215, 
   0.272462}, {66.6311, 0.272994}, {67.0469, 0.274345}, {67.5216, 
   0.275073}, {68.0551, 0.276204}, {68.5287, 0.278656}, {69.0018, 
   0.278633}, {69.4153, 0.279194}, {69.9463, 0.280652}, {70.3589, 
   0.282094}, {70.8298, 0.283566}, {74.2852, 0.290996}, {74.8094, 
   0.292765}, {75.3909, 0.293334}, {75.9134, 0.294814}, {76.3192, 
   0.295664}, {76.7824, 0.297675}, {77.2449, 0.297858}, {77.7645, 
   0.2998}, {78.168, 0.30081}, {78.6285, 0.301432}, {79.0308, 
   0.302366}, {79.49, 0.304195}, {80.063, 0.304802}, {80.4062, 
   0.305925}, {80.9204, 0.307709}, {81.3196, 0.309075}, {81.8322, 
   0.310024}, {82.2302, 0.311481}, {82.798, 0.313166}, {83.1948, 
   0.314054}, {83.7042, 0.314616}, {84.1563, 0.316528}, {84.6077, 
   0.31709}, {85.0585, 0.318668}, {85.5649, 0.320665}, {86.0143, 
   0.321727}, {86.4631, 0.32307}, {86.9113, 0.32364}, {87.4148, 
   0.325545}, {87.9175, 0.327214}, {88.3637, 0.328072}, {88.865, 
   0.32918}, {89.2543, 0.330895}, {89.8098, 0.331563}, {90.1981, 
   0.332838}, {90.6413, 0.334113}, {91.084, 0.335449}, {91.6365, 
   0.336975}, {92.078, 0.338379}, {92.5188, 0.339601}, {92.9592, 
   0.340094}, {93.454, 0.34272}, {93.9481, 0.343244}, {94.3319, 
   0.344898}, {94.8796, 0.346136}, {95.4265, 0.347236}, {95.9181, 
   0.349156}, {96.3545, 0.34968}, {96.7904, 0.351076}, {97.2803, 
   0.352784}, {97.7695, 0.353778}, {98.1495, 0.355334}, {98.746, 
   0.356799}, {99.1793, 0.358082}, {99.612, 0.358826}, {100.098, 
   0.360404}, {100.53, 0.361558}}
   ```

2.Then making the integral analytical(B,C and Capital Theta are my desired parameters to be evaluated)....

[image]

3.I will be happy if you can tell me where I go wrong and give me advice on this fitting[image]

Comment: Please post _Mathematica_ code, not pictures. One first thing is : in your definition use `g[T_]`.

Comment: It's because 50 isn't a variable...if you look at the documentation for [`NonlinearModelFit`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NonlinearModelFit.html), you aren't actually specifying a starting region for `T`. By writing `{T,50.,300.}` you're specifying three variables to minimize over.

Comment: Capital letters are a problem - is `C` defined elsewhere in your notebook?  Note it is black rather than blue.

Answer (score 4):

I have changed the name of some of the parameters (B->d,C->v,[Theta]->u). Using `mydata` (and changing the model to $\rho(T)=\rho(0)+(T/\theta)^n\int_0^{\theta/T}x^5/(e^x-1)(1-e^{-x})dx$ where $n=5$.

```
f[a_, b_, c_] := 
 c b^5/a^5 Integrate[x^5/(Exp[x] - 1) (1 - Exp[-x]), {x, 0, a/b}]
nlm = NonlinearModelFit[mydata, 
  d + f[u, t, v], {{u, 100}, {v, 0.2}, {d, 1}}, t]
```

This yields:

```
Column[{Normal@nlm, 
  Show[lp, Plot[Evaluate[nlm[x]], {x, 50, 100}, PlotStyle -> Red], 
   ImageSize -> 400],
  nlm["ParameterTable"]}, Frame -> All]
```

[image]

The features of the model can be explored.

Comment: Thanks for your all comments especially @ubpdqn

Comment: @ubpdqn..I try to fit my HC data using debye formula
f[a_, b_, c_] := 
 c b^3/a^3 Integrate[x^4 Exp[x]/(Exp[x] - 1)^2, {x, 0, a/b}]
and then
nlm = NonlinearModelFit[mydata, 
   d + f[a, t, c], {{a, 150}, {c, 70}, {d, 2.5}}, t];
I got a message 
NonlinearModelFit::nrlnum: The function value {Undefined,Undefined,...<<23>>,Undefined,Undefined,Undefined,Undefined,Undefined,Undefined,Undefined,Undefined,Undefined,Undefined,Undefined,Undefined,Undefined,<<400>>} is not a list of real numbers with dimensions {450} at {a,c,d} = {150.,70.,2.5}. >>

I could not locate where something goes wrong.